# grails database-migration-plugin: dbm-gorm-diff generates changesets for existing indexes

Tags: mysql, grails, grails-plugin

setup:

database-migration:1.4.0

mysql: 5.6.15

grails: 2.4.2

My workflow was this:

1. create an initial changelog.groovy w/dbm-generate-gorm-changelog
2. wipe and recreate DB w/grails.
3. dbm-changelog-sync.
4. modify model
5. dbm-gorm-diff change1.groovy

Newly-created change set contains createIndex directives referencing already-existing indice.

FWIW, looking into DATABASECHANGELOG, there's also a corresponding row with the duplicate ID, EXECTYPE: 'EXECUTED'.

This was reported b4 (http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRAILSPLUGINS-2748) but supposedly fixed.

Clues?

Thank you

Comment: Same issue with grails-2.3.11 and mysql